# Vue cli and vuetify how to use with local Roboto font

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, roboto

I have a Vue / Vuetify application under development created with the VUE CLI 3.x and would like to serve the Roboto font locally, not via Google cdn.

Has anyone accomplished this via webpack and the vue cli generated vuetify app project and if so how did you go about it?

Comment: What prevents you from just installing a package and importing the font-face in App.vue? https://www.npmjs.com/package/roboto-fontface

Comment: Actually, after revisiting this, probably that webpack does not automatically pick up the font files. This question may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348768/vuejs-webpack-importing-fonts-css-and-node-modules It suggests literally copying over the font files you need to your assets folder and manually defining the font-faces you require.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First install package `typeface-roboto` into your project.

Then import it into your main.js/index.js/boot.js or whatever:

```
import 'typeface-roboto/index.css';
```

Finally, update your `webpack.config.js` to allow the use of the font file types within the module rules i.e.:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            //other stuff
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
```

The font file types are `woff`, `woff2`, `eot` and `ttf`.

Comment: Thank you very much SnakeyHips this was perfect.  Did not need to modify a webpack.config.js (doesn't exist in my Vue CLI project), worked with first two steps alone.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me with only the first two steps.

Comment: The NPM package description says *"The Typefaces project is now deprecated."*. I see loads of other packages that claim to provide a roboto font, but I think the [fontsource one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/roboto) seems OK as replacement.

Comment: Quick update for @gertvdijk's comment: the syntax for installing and importing fontsource packages has changed slightly: 

`npm install @fontsource/roboto` and then `import "@fontsource/roboto";`

More details:
https://fontsource.org/docs/getting-started
https://fontsource.org/fonts/roboto

Comment: ``typeface-roboto`` is deprecated. Please replace it with ``fontsource-roboto``. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-roboto.

Answer (score 26):

With Vue CLI 3 + Vuetify:

- install typeface-roboto

  ```
    npm install --save @fontsource/roboto
  ```
- in `public/index.html`, **remove**

  ```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
  ```
- in `src/App.vue`, add

  ```
    <style lang="sass">
      @import '../node_modules/@fontsource/roboto/index.css'
    </style>
  ```

---

Edit: replaced `typeface-roboto` with `@fontsource/roboto`. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-roboto. Thanks @ikreb.

Comment: You're right. That's why the instruction is to "remove" the line, not to add it. I've highlighted the word **remove** in case it was not clear enough.

Comment: Yea, I didn't see that one before. Because I never had anything like that in my project, I didn't think that that's something to remove. My problem was solved by this: `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>` I missed the `rel="stylesheet"` attribute in the link.

Comment: ``typeface-roboto`` is deprecated. Please replace it with ``fontsource-roboto``. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-roboto.